# How to Auto Login from Wordpress into another Script?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add some functionality to my site and that is possible by the script I have made, but, I am not able auto-login from wordpress to that script.

The user,password and E-mail tables are same as Wordpress. I just need to enable Auto-login

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Comment: We're going to need *a lot* more information about your code to answer this. For instance, what kind of login system do you have? Do Wordpress users need to be associated to users in your other script somehow? Or are you just looking to retrieve the user data directly from Wordpress? As it stands, this question will be closed as "too broad" or "not enough information to reproduce" pretty quickly.